# MySQL: Better store an array/json or create different rows?

Tags: mysql, json

I have several garages and some garages are home for different carsharing cars.

Do I have to store the carsharing company as an array/json in one row or I create different rows for each carsharing company?

How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Different rows.  Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in different rows. Then you can query for them directly. If you'd store them as an array in one row this not so easy.

Think of the case you want to know the garage of a specific car then you fetch the row first and then find out if the array contains a specific value. This is not very flexible and takes a lot of time to compute if you have a large database.

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to know my idea only confirms again :) I was undecided whether an extra column would not be overkill.